# Rear shock size

Tags: honda, motorcycle, suspension

2014 honda stateline vt1300cra abs
I'm looking for the size of the rear shock absorber on this bike.  I've called a few different honda dealers and they tell me the oem shock is discontinued and can't till me the size to get a aftermarket one. Any help would be great

Comment: Contact the big shock absorber manufacturers and see if the do one Koni, Bosch etc

Comment: I can tell you it has a [99mm travel](http://www.wheels.ca/news/summer-riding-with-the-2010-honda-vt1300-cra-stateline/). I didn't find much info beyond that, though.

Comment: Can't help with size. I would try a VT1300 specific forum. You could find someone who has one to measure for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you would be told a rear suspension component from a 2014 would be discontinued. It might be actively produced any longer, but there could be dozens sitting on a warehouse shelf. I was able to locate the part on the parts fiche quite quickly here

http://www.ronayers.com/oemparts/a/hon/52c47f41f870024d205e759a/rear-shock-absorber-1

Here is another website offering the same part number for less:

http://www.partzilla.com/parts/detail/honda/HP-52400-MFY-305.html

I've found Ron Ayers to be rather reliable in terms of what is available and what is not. They also frequently indicate if a part has been superseded by a newer part number. If something isn't available, they don't list a price for it all.

As for the size of the shock, Japanese motorcycles do not have a standardized set of dimensions. Obviously, a specific shock has some dimensions. But fitment is often based on not only the eye to eye length of the shock, but many other factors as well. The attachment methods can also vary greatly. Although many rear shocks look like they have plenty of space, they are often quite a tight fit.

I can't find any catalog listings for an aftermarket shock for yours. I have had good luck [Works Performance](http://www.worksperformance.com/). They can manufacture a custom shock based off the OEM units dimensions.